# ngOptions in Angular not generating options

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cakephp

I need some help from angularjs ninjas...

I am currently using cake with angular. I have a rest controller which allows angular to communicate and get a list of options.. the service returns a serialized json as shown below

[image: Javascript object format]

Below is how im trying to generate the options for the dropdown :

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="trackerCtrl">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="trackers">Choose Tracker</label>
                <select id="tracker" name="tracker" ng-model="tracker"  ngOptions="tracker.Tracking.description for tracker in trackers" class="form-control custom-input tracker">
                    <option>Select Tracker</option>
                </select>
            </div>
 </div>
```

With the above, I get this in the DOM

```
<select id="tracker" name="tracker" ng-model="tracker" ngoptions="tracker.Tracking.description for tracker in trackers" class="form-control custom-input tracker ng-pristine ng-valid">
   <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
   <option value="Select Tracker">Select Tracker</option>
   <!-- Load options  -->
   <!--<option value=""></option>-->
</select>
```

I also tried using `ng-repeat` with the same result, so I am guessing the `JSON format is incorrect..`

Any help is greatly appreciated since I am baffled with this as it seems pretty straight forward. 
Kindly excuse my ignorance but i'm new to angular.

Comment: all looks good.. can you create a plnkr or something?  It will give better view.

Comment: ngOptions vs ng-options maybe? I'm not sure if both notations are supported, never used the one without the dash. Try it. If that doesn't work I guess the expression in ng-options is wrong. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: @dhavalcengg I ll try to create a jsfiddle if I have time, in the meantime i ll be checking out burzum's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="trackerCtrl">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="trackers">Choose Tracker</label>
                <select id="tracker" name="tracker" ng-model="tracker"  ng-options="tracker.Tracking.description for tracker in trackers" class="form-control custom-input tracker">
                    <option>Select Tracker</option>
                </select>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ngOptions** vs **ng-options**?

```
<select 
    id="tracker" 
    name="tracker"
    ng-model="tracker" 
    ng-options="tracker.Tracking.description for tracker in trackers"
    class="form-control custom-input tracker"
>
```

I'm not sure if both notations are supported, never used the one without the dash. Try it.

If that doesn't work I guess the expression in ng-options is wrong. [See the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason, and expressions seems to match with the example provided..